# How to get straight single quotes in verbatim and and codeexample

Tags: symbols, verbatim

I have in my documentation stuff like `print('abc')`, but it is turned into `print(’abc’)` (note the changed quote), which breaks compilation.

How could I make the environments `\begin{codeexample}` and `\begin{verbatim}` (bonus) print true quotes? (note that I still want the source to contain a true `'` as I still want to be able to copy/paste stuff from the source file that is more reliable than PDF).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,doc2]{ltxdoc} % doc2 is needed to force the old version, or links get colored in a weird red way even with hidelinks. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/822

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Warning: if you compile and get:
%% ERROR: Argument of \tikz@lib@matrix@with@options has an extra }.
%% make sure to fix catcodes around it as | is given a different meaning in ltxdoc.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros.tex}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{verbatim}
Hey, see this is'nt copy/pastable due to the simple 'quotes' (but "double quotes" seem to be fine).
\end{verbatim}

\begin{codeexample}[code only]
Hey, see this is'nt copy/pastable due to the simple 'quotes' (but "double quotes" seem to be fine).
\end{codeexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and the problem is solved =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Oh, interesting, thanks for the trick! I’m still interested by a solution for pdflatex but it love this simple solution!

Comment: You could use tcolorbox with minted. This way you would get nice syntax highlighting and could keep the Code in a seperate textfile. No need for Copy and Paste at all.

Comment: @Wamseln I do like `codeexample` because I can keep the code in the current file (sooo much tiny codes that it would be impossible to maintain), and also because it adds some link to the pgf style to quickly navigate in the documentation.